# Laravel artisan make:component outside resources folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7, laravel-artisan

When you run `php artisan make:component Foo` it will always be created inside `(root)/resources/views/component`.

How can I specify its "parent directory" or any specific directory **outside `resources` folder**?
I mean, like creating it at `(root)/custom-package/components`.

Is there any existing options does `make:component` command has? or I'm thinking few ways how to achieve this:

1. Create a custom `command` that will create the `php` and `blade` files to the directory I want.
2. Create a new command and extend the Laravel's `make:component` command to modify its path. (Currently, I can't find yet the Class where I can extend it.)

Or is there a `config` where I can set it?

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can use:

```
php artisan make:component Foo --path=your/custom/location
```

hope this help

Comment: Nope. `--path option does not exist.`.